# Can the set of odd primes be decomposed into $\Bbb{P} = A + B, $ for some $A,B \subset \Bbb{Z}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers, semigroups, additive-combinatorics

Can there ever exist infinite sets of integers $A, B$ such that $A + B = \{ a + b: a \in A, b \in B\} = \Bbb{P}$?  Where $\Bbb{P}$ is the set of odd primes?  You can include $0$ and / or $\pm$ odd primes if you must.  Maybe you can include $2$, I'm still not sure.. Confused!

This seems maybe easy, or maybe very difficult.  I will work on  my answer and update this here.

---

New notation, let $\Bbb{P}_o = $ the odd primes.

Here's working up finitely, an example.

$$A + B = \{2, 4, 8, 14, \dots\} \\
+ \\
\{3, 5, 9, 15, \dots \} = \{ p \in \Bbb{P}: p \geq 5\} = \Bbb{P}_o \setminus \{3\}
$$

The pattern seems to be ?

Comment: When you say $\Bbb P=A+B$, are you saying that $a\in A, b\in B\to a+b=p\in \Bbb P$, or are you saying $\Bbb P=A\cup B$?

Comment: @abiessu elementwise addition, the first one

Comment: In your example, you're already getting into trouble because 4 + 5 is not a prime. My instinct is that this isn't possible, but I don't have a good argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  If $A$ and $B$ each have numbers with two residues $\bmod 3$ there will be a sum that is a multiple of $3$ and not prime, so at least one is all the same residue class.  The other must have two residues so we get the primes that are $1 \bmod 3$ and $2 \bmod 3$.  In neither case can we get $3$ as a sum.